# Excluding energy required to lift an object, does it take more energy to accelerate a vehicle from stationary on a hill than on the flat?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, energy, friction

Excluding the energy required to overcome gravity, does it take more energy to accelerate a mass from stationary on an incline than compared to accelerating a mass on the flat?

For example compare

a car travels 200m, the first 100m is flat where it accelerates from 0 to 10m/s, the other 100m is an incline of a total 20m in height where it continues at 10/s.

to

a car travelling 200m, the first 100m is an incline of 20m where it accelerates from 0 to 10m/s, the rest of the 100m is flat where it continues at 10/s.

Would the rolling resistence - static or kinetic friction have an effect on the different scenarios?

Comment: "Excluding the energy required to overcome gravity" in that case it would be the same

Comment: ok, so the two cars in the example will use exactly the same energy to accelerate and continue?  Is there no penalty for accelerating on a hill compared to accelerating on the flat?

Comment: no because friction is not doing any work, also there is no energy dissipation, so the extra work you do becomes potential energy, but you say you want to ignore that extra work

Answer (score 1):

From physical point of view: It will be always the same.
From technical: If your hill will be steep enough, your car could lose traction.

Comment: I think this is what I was trying to get at, do you know much energy would be lost by the traction, how would I calculate that? Thank you for your input :-) I am sorry, I haven't refreshed my physics knowledge since gcse!

Comment: If it is sliding friction you just have to add bigger force than friction force to move and maintain connection with the ground (not moving mass center of your vehicle out of middle of it) And with rolling resistance it's similarly - you just need to care that rolling resistance is bigger than sliding friction.

Comment: Thank you @Michal Czarski